# Gap in vertical repeat of svg background

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a simple div, with an SVG set as background image with vertical repeat. On Chrome and Firefox, depending on the screen size, I see a gap in varying sizes (please resize the window).

https://jsfiddle.net/bartadaniel/ejtvy7po/9/

```css
.bg {
  width: 50%;
  height: 2000px;
  display: block;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='272' height='171' viewBox='0 0 272 171'> <rect class='cls-1' width='272' height='171' fill='green'/></svg>");
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the only solution that reliably tackled this issue was to convert the SVG to a pixel-based format, like JPG. Apparently, the browsers have no problem scaling pixels but causes side effects at edges when scaling vector-based formats.

Answer (score 4):

That's happening due to a combination of `background-size:contain` and the pixel dimensions of your svg.

You're seeing the browser try to scale the image so that nothing overflows the bounds of your `<div>`. When you combine that scaling with image pixel dimensions of 171 (can't be evenly multiplied into 2000px) you get lines showing you the sub pixels you're browser is trying to display.

Simply remove the `background-size:contain` to solve it.

---

Edit:

In the case where you **need** to contain width, there are a few tricks to help get a better result.

1. Make the background image dimensions multiples of 10. Square would be best with something like 100x100px but it could also be a rectangle (try to get close to your target width) like 1000x100px.
2. Set `background-size: 100% auto` instead of `contain`. This will stretch the image proportionalty to fill the container width.
3. Use `background-repeat: repeat-y` to force a vertical repeat so the browser is only doing the math on one axis.

Comment: that thing of removing background-size:contain was an epiphany

Comment: Thank you for your insight. This is a low-fi version of the issue I'm having. There the point is to fit an SVG horizontally while repeating it vertically. But indeed, it works for the problem I specified here.

Comment: Well you'll have the same problem regardless as long as you force the browser to do math that doesn't result in a whole number. Creating your image with dimensions as multiples of 10 (100, 1000, etc) will help but won't mitigate the issue completely.

Answer (score 2):

It is a problem of subpixel rendering.
Each browser rounds differently and SVG subpixel rendering is pretty messed up.

I suggest you to edit your SVG content to make it slightly bigger than your viewbox.

```
<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='272' height='171' viewBox='0 0 272 171'>
  <rect class='cls-1' y='-.5' width='272' height='172' fill='green'/>
</svg>
```

Obviously this trick doesn't work for all the background SVG, but might be useful in your case.

Answer (score 1):

If your SVG will still look acceptable with less anti-aliasing, you can change the anti-aliasing of the shapes in your SVG using the `shape-rendering` property. Example:

`<rect shape-rendering="crispEdges">`

You can use this on these elements: `<circle>, <ellipse>, <line>, <path>, <polygon>, <polyline>, and <rect>`.